# Integrate the Sass Version of MaterialCSS or Bulma Into Svelte

Tags: materialize, bulma, svelte, svelte-component, svelte-3

I am looking for instructions into how I can integrate the sass versions of Materializecss or Bulma into Svelte.  My goal is to be able to import individual components (like a button component or a card component) into an individual svelte component.  Furthermore, I would like to be able to take advantage of sass variables that Bulma offers.

I have looked for some tutorials on how to do this, but I have not found anything yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

You're not clear which part you are struggling with, but I will tell you how I am using Bulma with Svelte (and Sapper):

First of all, install the bulma dev dependency:

```
npm i -D bulma
```

then, install svelte-preprocess:

```
npm i -D svelte-preprocess
```

then, add svelte-preprocess to your rollup config:

```
  transformers: {
    scss: {
      includePaths: [
        'node_modules',
        'src'
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, ensure you pass the `preprocess` option to the `svelte` rollup plugin. Do this for both server and client if you're using Sapper.

```
svelte({
                dev,
                hydratable: true,
                emitCss: true,
                preprocess: sveltePreprocess(scssOptions)
            }),
```

Add an scss entrypoint file which includes your bulma dependencies:

```
// scss-entrypoint.scss
@charset 'utf-8';

@import 'node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all.sass';
@import 'node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all.sass';
@import 'node_modules/bulma/sass/grid/columns.sass';
...
```

Then, include the sass file in your root level comoponent (App.svelte) or (_layout.svelte) in Sapper:

```
<svelte:head>
  <style src="path/to/your/scss-entrypoint.scss"></style>
</svelte:head>
```

And that's it. I've written an talk on this here. See this and the next 5 slides:

https://antony.github.io/svelte-meetup-talk-oct-2019/#27

and there is a working demo here:

https://github.com/antony/svelte-meetup-talk-oct-2019

Answer (score 4):

My approach is a bit different. Here, I'm importing whole Bulma, but you can easily import just those components you really need. Then, I'm using `PurgeCSS` to clean up unused CSS during the build process.

1. *App.svelte*

```css
        <style lang="scss" global>
        @import "bulma/bulma";
        </style>
```

2. *rollup.config.js*

```js
    import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
    import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
    import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
    import purgecss from '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss';

    ...

        svelte({
            preprocess: sveltePreprocess({
                sourceMap: !production,
            }),
            dev: !production,
            emitCss: true
        }),
        postcss({
            plugins: [
                purgecss({
                    content: [
                        './src/**/*.svelte',
                        './node_modules/svelte/*.js',
                    ],
                }),
                autoprefixer()
            ],
            extract: true,
            minimize: production,
            sourceMap: !production,
        }),
    ...
```

There are few things which might be interesting:

1. style is `global`, because without that I get lots of 'unused CSS' warnings during the preprocess phase
2. `purgecss` needs link to `svelte/*.js` as well, to keep styles used in svelte base
3. `postcss` could be part of `sveltePreprocess`, but that gave me worse results, so I'm using standalone `postcss` with minification
4. I've tried using standalone `preprocess` with just `scss` and `globalStyle` preprocessors  (https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/blob/master/docs/preprocessing.md#stand-alone-processors), but that gave me same results as `sveltePreprocess` (time and file size was same)

Comment: I suppose smthing has changed in the purgecss or postcss module because I always get "[object Object] is not a PostCSS plugin" when trying to use your snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I've made a minimal commit on top of the default Svelte template that gets Bulma up and running in this example repo:

https://github.com/samal-rasmussen/svelte-bulma/commit/8afb28f6f157de89d6ace8310a31ab6d2b5e1776

Answer (score 1):

If you find it helpful I have developed a template to be able to use MaterializeCSS in Svelte. In addition I also added SMUI (Svelte Material UI) that adds scss functionalities to work the project styles with SASS.

[Svelte + MaterializedCSS + SMUI](https://github.com/rubenterre/Svelte-Materialize-SMUI)

Answer (score 0):

run the following command:

```
npx svelte-add@latest bulma
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SvelteKit, first install Bulma:

```
npm i -D bulma
```

Then globally load Bulma's variables and mixins from Vite's config, as well as your custom variables:

```js
// vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [sveltekit()],
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      sass: {
        additionalData: `
          @import "$lib/sass/_variables"
          @import "bulma/sass/utilities/_all"
        `,
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Define your own variables or those of Bulma that you want to redefine:

```scss
// src/lib/sass/_variables.sass
$primary: red
$secondary: orange
$tablet: 600px
```

Finally, import the modules you want from Bulma from the global file:

```scss
// src/lib/sass/global.sass
@import "bulma/sass/base/_all"
@import "bulma/sass/elements/_all"
@import "bulma/sass/form/_all"
@import "bulma/sass/components/_all"
@import "bulma/sass/grid/_all"
@import "bulma/sass/helpers/_all"
@import "bulma/sass/layout/_all"
```